# Can I derive a return type directly depending on a function parameter in TS?

Tags: typescript

I'm reading from a data source where I know the return type for each lookup key. I defined this in the type `DataLayout`.
I want to make the function `getItem()` generic and get the correct return type accordingly.

```
type DataLayout = {
  a: string
  b: number
}

const getItem = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(key: string & keyof T) => {
  return getExternalItem(key) as T[typeof key]
}

const result = getItem<DataLayout>('a')
```

but `result` is of type `string | number`.

How do I make it `string` only? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a bit different way:

```js
type DataLayout = {
  a: string
  b: number
}

declare var data: DataLayout;

const dataLayout = <Obj,>(obj: Obj) => <Prop extends keyof Obj>(prop: Prop) => obj[prop]

const withData = dataLayout(data)

const getItem = withData('a') // string
const getItem2 = withData('b') // number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAZOID2BXYUC8UDeAsAFBRRwBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYlkBGVTGAthxDokAviRIATCAGMANnDrQAbvKjiElWOpTosAbjHEpaJrVVbUmbHgA8AeQ4ArADQA%20ABRpHVew4CUuFyhrAAU6NDAoCAAPYAgmcWooAGsIdAAzKB93MDCwKlDw-xxAzwcAbRzwgF0DIxNsAHcGYAALeERcM0RtSzc1RF9a41MWCGAASVjeTqbW9rg3AHI4Rf8AejWaemY2Q2HsUYmpgCYZ5rb1JY5VqA2oHn5BAyA)

In 79.8% cases, you should not use explicit generic, TS should infer it from some value

Answer (score 1):

In addition to captain-yossarian's anwer, I like to use a class for this. Also, I added an extra check to the `getItem` function to make sure that `getItem('c')` will give a compiler error.

```
type DataLayout = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
};

class Entity<T extends Record<string, unknown>> {
  getItem<K extends keyof T>(key: K & keyof T): T[K] {
    return null as any;
  }
}

const ent = new Entity<DataLayout>();

// type of result is string
const result = ent.getItem('a');

// this will give a compiler error:
ent.getItem('c');
```